# The existence of conditional expectation, $(\mathscr{S},\Sigma,\mu) $ $\sigma$-finite space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(\mathscr{S},\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and let $f$ be $\Sigma$-measurable and integrable over $\mathscr{S}$. Let $\Sigma_0$ be a $\sigma$-algrbra satisfying $\Sigma_0\subseteq \Sigma$. Show that there is a unique function $f_0$ which is $\Sigma_0$-measurable such that $\int fgd\mu=\int f_0gd\mu$ for every $\Sigma$-measurable $g$ for which the integrals are finite.
i

My attempt:

Define $\phi(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ for $A\in \Sigma_0$. Since $f$ is integrable, then $\phi$ is a set function. So applying Radon-Nikodym theorem, there is unique $f_0$ $\Sigma_0$- measurable such that $\phi(A)=\int_A f_0d\mu$ for $A\in \Sigma_0$.

Hence, $\int_A fd\mu=\int_A f_0d\mu$ for $A\in \Sigma_0$.

Next, consider $g=\mathcal{X}_E$ for $E\in\Sigma_0$ is true. And simple function. For the nonnegative function use monotone convergence theorem. For general $g$ consider $g^+-g^-$.

Is it correct my approach?

Comment: Shouldn't it be every $\Sigma_0$-measurable $g$?

Comment: I think you have the right idea. You apply the Radon-Nikodym derivative and then construct the integral from the resulting measure. I don't know if you left it out because this is just a proof sketch, but it's important to make sure that $\phi(\cdot)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_f(\cdot) := \int_\cdot f\,d\mu$. However this should be simple.